# iptraf shows traffic on UDP/443, why?

Tags: linux, tcp, udp, traffic

Somehow, `iptraf` is telling me that I am getting traffic via port 443 in UDP instead of TCP.

I checked the firewall several times, and UDP port 443 is definitely not open. I have that TCP port (apache2) which is open, though.

Why would IPTraf report traffic of the wrong category? Should I be worried?

[image]

Comment: You are using chrome browser. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC

Comment: @IporSircer, no. I'm not running *Chrome*. However, it is likely that *Firefox* supports it too. And I have *SeaMonkey* which supports it since version 2.25. So that would be the one. That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: The 443/UDP that I have here is from DNSCrypt; it could also be QUIC as @IporSircer says.